# How to send message as user to slack using slack bot user token

Tags: slack, slack-api

Im trying to send messages to slack using my user token. But the messages show up as being sent by the user who installed the app to the workspace. The documentation says it won't work for new slack apps but it doesn't say which version. At the moment I'm sending

```
 resp = slack_client.chat_postMessage(
                channel=my_channel.u_id,
                text=text,
                token=token.token,
                username="U048EAF2KT7"
            )
```

In the username field, I've tried, "Bot", use email, etc. The message is posted but not as the intended user.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that you're using the new Slack app, which doesn't fully support sending messages as another user. But if you request the `chat:write.customize` scope you can make a call to `chat.postMessage` with the bot token (xoxb) to [send a message as another entity](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#authorship).